# What is a "notice on answer"? Who gives them?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Recently I got a notice on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137518/proof-for-linear-combination-of-multivariate-normal-x/137521#137521). This is the first time I have received a notice. I understand comments. Now I am wondering what this "notice on answer" is? I am also interested to know who gives these notices to the answers, because no name is displayed as there would be if someone made a comment. Are the notices used for answers only or are they applicable to questions as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to a "Post notice."  These can be added to posts for various reasons:

- Citation needed

  > This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this post by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
  >   current event
- Post is related to a rapidly changing event.
- Insufficient explanation

  > We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Only moderators can add these notices.  I added one to your original post because it was brief and telegraphic: it clearly did not meet our site standards and was at risk of being downvoted and even deleted.

When you amplified your answer, and I observed that you had done that, I removed the notice.  Unfortunately, there is no notification mechanism to let me (or other moderators) know that a change has been made to such an answer.  Consequently, you can still find a few answers on our site that now look great but still have post notices.  If you come across anything like that, then just flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand the difference between comment and notice.Also I will flag answer if I see great answer with post notice.

Comment: Do all such notices come manually from moderators? I was under the impression that there is an algorithm in the background that adds them automatically.

Comment: @gung Sometimes the "Community" bot might add such notices; I cannot recall whether it does or not.  Pretty obviously it cannot add the "rapidly changing event" notice or the "citation" notice.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the "insufficient explanation" one. There may be (or may used to have been) other notices that seemed automatic as well.